# Another place to download Django?

Tags: django

Is there another place than https://www.djangoproject.com/ to download Django? The site appears to be down and has been for some time now.

Comment: Works for me. Have you tried installing via pip?

Comment: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/djangoproject.com

Comment: This question is indicative of someone in need of basic computer training / desktop support and not a programming question that fits within StackOverflow very well.  Questions like this are best asked in other support channels.  In this case, Django has an active IRC room on freenode where this question would have been more appropriate.

Comment: I used a VPN and it started working now.

Answer (score 3):

While the site loads for me (https://www.djangoproject.com/download/), you can also install it via pip:

```
pip install Django
```

or get the lastest development (!) version via pip + git:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/django/django.git#egg=django
```

or get the latest development (!) version from git directly:

```
git clone git://github.com/django/django.git
```

For ease of portability, consider installing Django in a [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.org).